# regex expression to validate numbers only?

Tags: asp.net

Any one can tell me the regex expressions to validate the following?

1) My account number should be 3-7 digits (and only numbers)
2) My meter reading number should be exactly 6 digits (Only numbers)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\d{3,7}` and `\d{6}`, respectively.